# Clear ListView if response is a empty array?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I have two spinners the first one for month and the second for years.I am trying to call a method send_date() if on Item Selected is called for any of the 2 spinners.

> So I have two problems:- 1)send_date() gets called twice the first
>   time it gets the correct data as expected but the 2nd time it returns
>   a empty array. 2)When I select another month or year the old data does
>   not get removed that is the list does not refresh.

The following is my code for on Item Selected :-

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                int i = spinYear.getSelectedItemPosition();
                selected_year = years.get(i);
                Log.d("Selection Year",selected_year);
                tv_year.setText(selected_year);

                try {
                    send_date();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

And for the month spinner:-

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {

                int j = spinMonths.getSelectedItemPosition();
                selected_month = Months[j];
                Date date = null;
                try {
                    date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").parse(selected_month);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTime(date);
                tv_month.setText(String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1));

                Log.d("Selection Month",selected_month);
                try {
                    send_date();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

On response I call the following method for populating the list view with data:-

```
public void showBS(String response)
{
    ParseBS_all pb = new ParseBS_all(response);
    pb.parseBS();

     bl = new BS_allList(getActivity(),ParseBS_all.doc_no,ParseBS_all.balance,ParseBS_all.total,ParseBS_all.vat,ParseBS_all.profit);
    lv_bsall.setAdapter(bl);

}
```

This is the code for the send_date method:-

```
    //This method is used to send month and year
    private void send_date() throws JSONException {

        final String year = tv_year.getText().toString();
        final String month = tv_month.getText().toString();


        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, SEND_DATE,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        //display.setText("This is the Response : " + response);
                        String resp = response.toString().trim();

                        if (resp.equals("Nothing to display"))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Nothing to Display", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                            bl.clear();
                            lv_bsall.setAdapter(bl);
                            bl.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Response" + response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.d("RESPONSE for date", response.toString().trim());
                            showBS(response);
                        }


                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                GlobalClass gvar = (GlobalClass) getActivity().getApplicationContext();
                String dbname = gvar.getDbname();
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put(KEY_DBNAME, dbname);
                params.put(KEY_MONTH, month);
                params.put(KEY_YEAR,year);
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQ = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        requestQ.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Adapter code for list view.

```
public class BS_allList extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{

    private String[] doc_no;
    private String[] balance;
    private String[] total;
    private String[] vat;
    private String[] profit;
    private Activity context;

    public BS_allList(Activity context, String[] doc_no, String[]balance, String[] total, String[] vat, String[] profit)
    {
        super(context, R.layout.bs_list_all, doc_no);
        this.context =context;
        this.doc_no= doc_no;
        this.balance = balance;
        this.total = total;
        this.vat=vat;
        this.profit = profit;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View listViewItem, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (null == listViewItem)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bs_list_all, null, true);
        }
        TextView tv_docNo = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvdoc_no);
        TextView tv_balance = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_balance);
        TextView tv_tot = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_total);
        TextView tv_vat = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_vat);
        TextView tv_pf = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_profit);

        tv_docNo.setText(doc_no[position]);
        tv_balance.setText(balance[position]);
        tv_tot.setText(total[position]);
        tv_vat.setText(vat[position]);
        tv_pf.setText(profit[position]);

        return listViewItem;
    }
}
```

Also note that I have set the spinner to point to the current month and year so the first time it works properly.
I am new to programming so any help or suggestion is appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: use  adapter.clear

Comment: @KhizarHayat I have tried notifyDataSetChanged() but it did not work.Do you know why it did not work?

Comment: clear your `List`, call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()`, set adapter to your listView.

Comment: @SripadRaj I did try notifyDatasetChanged() it did not work in this case.And I don't know why?

Comment: after you call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` set the `adapter` to your `listView` again.

Comment: @SripadRaj I tried your solution but it doe not seem to work.

Comment: @KhizarHayat adapter.clear gives me java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: can you post your listview code?

Comment: show your send_date(); method

Comment: @AndroidNewBee You need to initialize your bl with null values when you are getting empty response and then just notifydatasetchanged or set adapter to spinner and it will clear data

Comment: @Vickyexpert i tried doing what you said it gives a  java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null exception

Comment: @AndroidNewBee can you show adapter class BS_allList file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114234/discussion-between-androidnewbee-and-vickyexpert).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @AndroidNewBee,

As per our discussion made following changes in your code and you will get proper output and it will resolve your issues.

```
  if (resp.equals("Nothing to display"))
  {
      Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Nothing to Display", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      bl = new BS_allList(getActivity(),{""},{""},{""},{""},{""});
      lv_bsall.setAdapter(bl);
  }
```

And second is check validation as below,

```
  try {
         if((selected_year != null & selected_year.length > 0 ) & (tv_month.getText().toString() != null & tv_month.getText().toString().length > 0))
         {
            send_date();
         }

  } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First you shouldn't be using so many `String[]`, instead wrap them in a class

```
Class BSDataModel{
    private String doc_no;
    private String balance;
    private String total;
    private String vat;
    private String profit;
   //getters and setters
}
```

Now the `reponse` result should be added as in ,it returns `List<BSDataModel>`

```
   List<BSDataModel> reponseList = new ArrayList<>();

    //for example adding single response
    for(int i=0;i<jsonArrayResponse.length();i++){
        BSDataModel singleResponse = new BSDataModel();
        singleResponse.setDocNo(jsonArrayResponse.get(i).getString("doc_no"));
        singleResponse.setBalace(jsonArrayResponse.get(i).getString("balance")); 
        //etc..finall add that single response to responseList
        reponseList.add(singleResponse);
    }
```

**BS_allList.java**

```
public class BS_allList extends ArrayAdapter<BSDataModel>
{

    private List<BSDataModel> bsList;
    private Activity context;

    public BS_allList(Activity context,List<BSDataModel> bsList)
    {
        super(context, R.layout.bs_list_all, bsList);
        this.context =context;
        this.bsList = bsList;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View listViewItem, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (null == listViewItem)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bs_list_all, null, true);
        }
        TextView tv_docNo = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvdoc_no);
        TextView tv_balance = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_balance);
        TextView tv_tot = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_total);
        TextView tv_vat = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_vat);
        TextView tv_pf = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_profit);
        BSDataModel bsData = bsList.get(position);
        tv_docNo.setText(bsData.getDoc());
        tv_balance.setText(bsData.getBalance());
        tv_tot.setText(bsData.getTot());
        tv_vat.setText(bsData.getVat());
        tv_pf.setText(bsData.getPF());

        return listViewItem;
    }
}
```

Now in your class

```
BS_allList bl = new BS_allList(getActivity(),responseList);//which you got above
```

After receiving new Response

```
      // remove old data

        responseList.clear(); // list items in the sense list of array used to populate listview

           if(newresponseArray.size() > 0){
             for(int i=0;i<newjsonArrayResponse.length();i++){
                BSDataModel singleResponse = new BSDataModel();
                singleResponse.setDocNo(newjsonArrayResponse.get(i).getString("doc_no"));
                singleResponse.setBalace(newjsonArrayResponse.get(i).getString("balance")); 
                //etc..finall add that single response to responseList
                reponseList.add(singleResponse);
            }
           }

        //refresh listview
        bl.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I am new to programming I did not understand remove old data concept.When I do notify data set changed isn't that suppose to erase the list and populate it with the new data.

Comment: Nope, it will refresh based on list of items you used to populate.your using custom adapter called BS_allList , can you post that class?

Comment: I still did not understand why the 2nd time the method is getting called why does it send a empty response.Can you tell why?

Comment: Thank you so much Rajan KS.

Comment: Your Welcome :) this is actually the correct and best approach. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
1. adapter.clear();
2. Add/Remove your list Items.
3. listview.setAdapter(adapter);
4. adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

this procedure should work.

Comment: This gives me an error java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: try to notify adapter  after setting list view adapter

Comment: I tried both the solutions Sathish and @GaneshGudghe both ain't working for me.